# Update object with missing json properties reverted to default value

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

This is my object:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "discriminator": "product"
}
```

My Code:

```
@objcMembers
class RLBCategory: Base {

enum CategoryType: String {
    case product
    case event
    case workshop
    case industry
}

// MARK: - Properties
dynamic var name: String?
dynamic var discriminator: String?

override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map: map)

    name <- map["name"]
    discriminator <- map["discriminator"]
      }
   }
  var json = ["id": 1, "name": "Sport", "discriminator": "product"] as [String: Any]
  var mapper = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: json)
  var category = RLBCategory(map: mapper)

  XCTAssertEqual(category?.id, 1)
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.name, "Sport")
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.discriminator, RLBCategory.CategoryType.product.rawValue)

  json = ["id": 1, "name": "Football", "discriminator": "product"] as [String: Any]
  mapper = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: json)
  category = RLBCategory(map: mapper)

  XCTAssertEqual(category?.id, 1)
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.name, "Football")
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.discriminator, RLBCategory.CategoryType.product.rawValue)

  json = ["id": 1, "discriminator": "product"] as [String: Any]
  mapper = Map(mappingType: .fromJSON, JSON: json)
  category = RLBCategory(map: mapper)

  XCTAssertEqual(category?.id, 1)
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.name, "Football")
  XCTAssertEqual(category?.discriminator, 
  RLBCategory.CategoryType.product.rawValue)
```

I expected all unit test assertion being `true`. The updated object name should not be modified because not being in JSON.

`XCTAssertEqual(category?.name, "Football")` being `false` because updated object name is now nil.

How to update Json Object with missing Json Properties to Default Value?

Comment: Aren't you creating each time a new object `mapper` that is forgetting what is was before and so its values like `name`?

Comment: @larme This is the problem. Thanks. Please post as a response so i can upvote.